# Make overlay menu disappear on link click

Tags: javascript, css

To start, this question only applies to the mobile version of the site, so you'll have to shrink your browser down to a width of less than 1000 px just to see the menu.

On that mobile layout, I've got a button that makes an overlay with 4 links appear. There's an "X" to close the overlay, but I want it to close when the user clicks on the links, as well. So far I haven't been able to make it work. Here's the code I'm using:

https://codepen.io/dftg/pen/oZyBpq

this is the javascript that I'm trying to adapt to make this work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});

$('#hider').click(function() {
    $('menu').addClass('hidemenu');
});
```

Comment: change `$('menu').addClass('hidemenu');` to `$('#menu').addClass('hidemenu');`. and in your codepen, you need to add jquery https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/RpJpma

Comment: it doesn't look like that's making any difference

Comment: I edited the code in my original post to include another script I'm also using, which I think might possibly be interfering with the one that I can't successfully implement.